# Why does typescript expect 'never' as function argument when retrieving the function type via generics?

Tags: typescript

I'm currently trying to switch from TS 2.6 to 3.4 and I'm running into weird problems. This previously worked, but now it's showing me a compiler error:

```
type MyNumberType = 'never' | 'gonna';
type MyStringType = 'give' | 'you';
type MyBooleanType = 'up' 

interface Bar {
    foo(key: MyNumberType): number;
    bar(key: MyStringType): string;
    baz(key: MyBooleanType): boolean;
}

function test<T extends keyof Bar>(bar: Bar, fn: T) {
    let arg: Parameters<Bar[T]>[0];
    bar[fn](arg); // error here
}
```

Error as follows:

```
Argument of type 'Parameters<Bar[T]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
Type '[number] | [string] | [boolean]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
Type '[number]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

The Typescript playground tells me that the expected argument of the function is of type 'never':
[image]

I don't expect an error here at all. There is only one function argument, and the type of the argument gets inferred via `Parameters`. Why is does the function expect `never`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler does not understand that `arg` and `bar[fn]` are [correlated](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). It treats both of them as uncorrelated union types, and thus expects that [every combination of union constituents is possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051#issuecomment-405358173) when most combinations are not.

In TypeScript 3.2 you'd've just gotten an error message saying that `bar[fn]` doesn't have a call signature, since it is a union of functions with different parameters.  I doubt that any version of that code worked in TS2.6; certainly the code with `Parameters<>` wasn't in there since conditional types weren't introduced until TS2.8.  I tried to recreate your code in a TS2.6-compatible way like

```
interface B {
    foo: MyNumberType,
    bar: MyStringType,
    baz:MyBooleanType
}

function test<T extends keyof Bar>(bar: Bar, fn: T) {
    let arg: B[T]=null!
    bar[fn](arg); // error here
}
```

and [tested in TS2.7](https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=2.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiByBXAtgIwgJwCrmgXigHIA7CAN00KgB8iBzAe2OIENCBuAKFElhAGVgGAJbE6OXgUJ1hFKrUIgGiDt1x8AQgwYAbCC2IT8RRGCqdOo4JgBmLAMbQNLDFADenKF6g3tACgBrCBAALj4kNEwjAEow4hR0DC5vKFQXQOCwuEERMRiwgGchUTpk7zSALwzQzW09A3zUuv1iLgBfCytbByd3T29fBiyEBKjcABp+rzSMYZySo0mUypC4LV0Wo04OzhtEYntgYSYoayKAHiwoCAAPa2IAEwKoIKUbKGcMAD4-GbDP8Y+YhhLDRPopPTAKAuOj-ADaWAAunh4jodABCKapFxwmzERF+GHRdhQAD0pOuGAwDFcAAtMBBtkA) but it still gives an error.  So I'm going to assume that this code never really worked.

As for the `never` issue: TypeScript 3.3 introduced [support for calling unions of functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) by requiring that the parameters be the *intersection* of the parameters from the union of functions.  That is an improvement in some cases, but in your case it wants the parameter to be the intersection of a bunch of distinct string literals, which gets collapsed to `never`.  That's basically the same error as before ("you can't call this") represented in a more confusing way.

---

The most straightforward way for you to deal with this is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), since you are smarter than the compiler in this case:

```
function test<T extends keyof Bar>(bar: Bar, fn: T) {
    let arg: Parameters<Bar[T]>[0] = null!; // give it some value
    // assert that bar[fn] takes a union of args and returns a union of returns
    (bar[fn] as (x: typeof arg) => ReturnType<Bar[T]>)(arg); // okay
}
```

A type assertion is not safe, you this does let you lie to the compiler:

```
function evilTest<T extends keyof Bar>(bar: Bar, fn: T) {
    // assertion below is lying to the compiler
    (bar[fn] as (x: Parameters<Bar[T]>[0]) => ReturnType<Bar[T]>)("up"); // no error!
}
```

So you should be careful.  There is a way to do a completely type safe version of this, forcing the compiler to do code flow analysis on every possibility:

```
function manualTest<T extends keyof Bar>(bar: Bar, fn: T): ReturnType<Bar[T]>;
// unions can be narrowed, generics cannot
// see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995
// and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085
function manualTest(bar: Bar, fn: keyof Bar) {
    switch (fn) {
        case 'foo': {
            let arg: Parameters<Bar[typeof fn]>[0] = null!
            return bar[fn](arg);
        }
        case 'bar': {
            let arg: Parameters<Bar[typeof fn]>[0] = null!
            return bar[fn](arg);
        }
        case 'baz': {
            let arg: Parameters<Bar[typeof fn]>[0] = null!
            return bar[fn](arg);
        }
        default:
            return assertUnreachable(fn);
    }
}
```

But that is so brittle (requires code changes if you add methods to `Bar`) and repetitive (identical clauses over and over) that I usually prefer the type assertion above.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: is there no way typescript can infer the true branch of the generic type without using the discriminated union?

Comment: Unfortunately [not](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995#issuecomment-363265172).

Comment: sorry about being a little unclear about _what_ previously worked. obviously i didn't use `Parameters`, but in the end with "it previously worked" i rather meant it didn't show any errors, not that it provided correct typings (which is stupid anyways). i'm also not a friend of type assertions, but in this case it's better than populating actual code execution with redundant statements.

Answer (score 1):

The way `barFn` is declared is equivalent to:

```
type Foo = (key: number) => number;
type Bar = (key: string) => string;
type Baz = (key: boolean) => boolean;

function test1(barFn: Foo | Bar | Baz) {    
    barFn("a"); // error here
}
```

`barFn`'s parameter will be an `intersection` of types rather than `union`. The type `never` is a bottom type and it happens because there is no intersection between `number`, `string` and `boolean`.

Ideally you want to declare `barFn` as an intersection of the three function types. e.g:

```
function test2(barFn: Foo & Bar & Baz) {    
    barFn("a"); // no error here
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really solve the problem of accessing types of function parameters of an interface in a generic way. `keyof Bar` correctly gives me a union type in the first place containing all property names of `Bar` (which i actually want), and `Parameters<Bar[T]>[0]` correctly gives me the type of the first parameter of the specified function, this also works. i can't pass the functions themselves unfortunately, that's why this is not the answer to my question

Comment: @GernotRaudner Yeah I understand I'll try and find a solution with generics, but your question title is misleading :p

Comment: sorry, i updated the question title, hope it's clearer now. i also updated the sample to be more specific about the requirements