# Error with Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try to map format function by a type, but I get the error:

> `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Here is the code with the error:

```
type Type = 'datetime' | 'number' | 'string';

const mapTypeToFormat = (type: Type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'datetime':
      return (value: string) => new Date(value).toLocaleDateString('en');

    case 'number':
      return (value: number) => value.toLocaleString('en');

    case 'string':
    default:
      return <V,>(value: V): V | '—' => value ? value : '—';
  }
};

interface AppProps {
  type: Type;
  value: number | string;
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => {
  const { value, type } = props;
  const formattedValue = mapTypeToFormat(type)(value); // Error here on "value"

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <div>{formattedValue}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mclean-zmng6?file=/src/App.tsx

Could you explain to me where I'm wrong? Thanks!

Comment: codesandbox is empty (only initial code)

Comment: First wrong thing: your `AppProps` type is too wide since `const props: AppProps = { type: 'number', value: "hmm" }` compiles without error.  You want a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) like `type AppProps = { type: "datetime", value: number } | { type: "number", value: number } | { type: "string", value: string }`.  This won't solve your problem, but it does reduce it to a previously asked question I can link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does typescript expect 'never' as function argument when retrieving the function type via generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572797/why-does-typescript-expect-never-as-function-argument-when-retrieving-the-func).  Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: How to map objects in a discriminated union to functions they can be called with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781010/typescript-how-to-map-objects-in-a-discriminated-union-to-functions-they-can-be).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30851](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more.