# How do I declare this generic object type mapping correctly?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to declare a type that takes the keys of one type and maps them to a transformation function that takes values of the corresponding key to another type (`string[]` in this case). I think I declared the type correctly, but when I attempt to use it and access the transformation functions, they're not being typed correctly.

```
type ArgMap<T extends {}> = { [K in keyof T]?: (value: T[K]) => string[] }
```

If I use a `string` as a key, the type of the transform function can't be determined and is `any`. It will work fine if I use a constant string that matches one of the keys.

[image]

For my purposes, this strict type safety isn't necessary so I'll likely just make the arguments `any` and move on, but I'm wondering if this can be changed to make it work.

```
type ArgMap<T extends {}> = { [K in keyof T]?: (value: T[K]) => string[] }

interface MyOptions {
  foo: string;
  bar: { [key: string]: string[] };
  biz: number;
}

const argMap: ArgMap<MyOptions> = {
  foo: value => [value],
  bar: value => Object.keys(value),
  biz: value => [value.toString()],
};
const transformOptions = (options: MyOptions) => {
  const args: string[] = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(options)) {
    const map = argMap[key]; // error here
    if (map && value) {
      args.push.apply(args, map(value));
    }
  }
  return args;
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwLIEMwB4AqUIA9gQB2AJgM5QDeAvgHxQC8lUA2gNJQCWhUA1hCAHsAZlEwBdAPwAuKAAoAbigA2AVwgzMbMQEoGdUsDhcEzMVCoAoC1wJwhKAMbQkIAPJhgHAYXIULUKCEBARkDI0IEAG5-KAAjFDgZChY+EFDDYzF08JMzKmiA2I4ALxlCFQBbWIg4aMsLB28DKATkNBl4NowXd08mukY-AKCQqEVVaHo6ZnG1MQAaGPjEseU1PShXWIArCAdgADpU0gU1iG1FwpKZWcnp24PgAQBlDIjZbQWLfIam4ChDCgfEE4BVel4fAw5AIPBDSDIerCmroppQYo0fP9WvCoGFjKYoaYCoEBHA5BjmsxUvNVhMzMJNjs9ociBkICcYX0fNpdEMAlAKf8Kmgoa1UGAqfwxMSAhwRLJhWAoAAyZW0tS8mL8lqIUgHMAqUgACwOaDAShAsmxNMVpwmPJl5hilgCcAgwBUcG42Lq0SAA)

Comment: The problem is in the assumption that Object.entries will return the type of key when in reality it just returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map alone the way I had been using it was not enough to help the type system figure out the types. If only there was a way to assert some things about the existence of a key in an object and its corresponding value, this would work for me but it's not enough.

Ultimately I needed a way to ensure that:

1. the key is indeed a member of an object
2. the value of the corresponding key is of some type

The solution I ended up going with is taking this object map and making a function out of it. Below, the `prop()` function does all the heavy lifting of ensuring the types are correct.

```
const mapValue = (options: MyOptions, key: string): string[] | null => {
  const prop = <K extends keyof MyOptions>(key: K, map: (value: MyOptions[K]) => string[]) => {
    const value = options[key]
    return value ? map(value) : null
  };
  switch (key) {
    case 'foo': return prop(key, value => [value]);
    case 'bar': return prop(key, value => Object.keys(value));
    case 'biz': return prop(key, value => [value.toString()]);
    default: return null;
  }
};
const transformOptions = (options: MyOptions) => {
  const args: string[] = [];
  for (const key of Object.keys(options)) {
    const value = mapValue(options, key)
    if (value) {
      args.push(...value);
    }
  }
  return args;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAHMwD2IAzsgN4BQyyM++AXMkWFKAOYDclyARnFA6WQBtANYR0DJixCsAupOZshs5AF9OVbsABeDEAFcAtt2idV5cgkJNkhuNgBqcADb6UAXmQAKfLgLEGDBw8awAaZDEJRkUZAEoFaVZlZAAfZANnZ2R3AD4yLitiMGRsKF9s5AAeAGlkCAAPSBAAExJI-Bg0LD9rHK9Ihmrwu2wGLwA3FzdA7pDiIWrZWOy8qSUllfyqKkKbSdcPZF85olFxWS4qKAgwfSgQZH23ZAB+W3sJqYhlvX1MrnUXCIAHdgGAEAALbyRZYUbbIBBwIgoADkNHwKIY11u9xKZWw-XE4SeHjyQhJSw020RyOQKN4UExyGxdwepV8hPQxK+m0w3AAVhAEGAAHSRIifA6xWJUnZI1FabRMlm49kEyLcg6bclfEVgfAAZRirC8sUpl2QzQg8D+YCxN1Z6T+zip5kBu2KzDgxBoUEMwX8JE8Ph6AS6Aesy1yWwR1mKfFYRAS6wqyipvu8Hoi4iOnT5guFYvEEuOgelMZ2ccePM8IycBxDJ3CMItwE6krcsItVATRBF2H0RAhXhFo5JMot5ioU+ZDtxvbMnCAA)

Answer (score 2):

That's a problem of `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` returning `string` instead of `keyof T` even if you use their generic overloads as this is how, for example, the corresponding overload for `Object.entries` is defined in the standard library:

```js
entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
```

In your case, though, the generic overload is not used, because the non-generic one matches, resulting in the `key` being of type `string` and `value`, even worse, `any`:

```js
entries(o: {}): [string, any][];
```

From here you can either add your own overload* or assert the `key` to be `keyof MyOptions` as you know is the case: `const map = argMap[key as keyof MyOptions];`.The type of `map` will now be a union of transformer function signatures (plus `undefined` that is excluded in the type guard right after that):

```js
((value: string) => string[]) | ((value: {
    [key: string]: string[];
}) => string[]) | ((value: number) => string[]) | undefined
```

This, however, uncovers the next problem: when you try to call `map`, the type of `value` is inferred as `never` because `string & { [key:string]: string[]; } & number` is an impossible intersection. I won't be able to give you a better explanation than [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz), so do [take a look at this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576136/11407695). A TL;DR of it is that this is an unfortunate caveat of [TS 3.3 handling of calling union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).

So, now `map` type is inferred as `const map: (value: never) => string[]`. Another assertion is in order, and most likely it is the best that can be done here:

```js
const map = argMap[key as keyof MyOptions] as (val: MyOptions[keyof MyOptions]) => string[];
```

It is far from ideal, but still better than resorting to `any`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwLIEMwB4AqUIA9gQB2AJgM5QDeAvgHxQC8lUA2gNJQCWhUA1hCAHsAZlEwBdAPwAuKAAoAbigA2AVwgzMbMQEoGdUsDhcEzMVCoAoC1wJwhKAMbQkIAPJhgHAYXIULUKCEBARkDI0IEAG5-KAAjFDgZChY%20EFDDYzF08JMzKmiA2I4ALxlCFQBbWIg4aMsLB28DKATkNBl4NowXd08mukY-AKCQqEVVaHo6ZnG1MQAaGPjEseU1PShXWIArCAdgADpU0gU1iG1FwpKZWcnp24PgAQBlDIjZbQWLfIam4ChDCgfEE4BVel4fAw5AIPBDSDIerCmroppQYo0fP9WvCoGFjKYoaYCoEBHA5BjmsxUvNVhMzMJNjs9ociBkICcYX0fNpdH4YgEKf8Kmgoa1UGAqfwWuRUgzEVzSGYUORTkoEW4kT5JYIRPK4ToNniIkSrAEAhwRLJhWAoAAyW20tS8-lm7EHMAqUgACwOaDAShAsmxNOtqqd2mJAUsUZicAgwBUcG42Lq0SAA)

---

* If you are sure your codebase does not rely on object mutability, you can add overloads to the `entries` method that will save you from at least one assertion. I usually end up using something like that:

```js
type TupleEntries<T extends readonly any[]> = {
    [ P in keyof T ] : P extends Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[]> ? [ `${P & string}` , T[P] ] : T[P]
};

interface ObjectConstructor {
    entries<T extends readonly any[]>(o: T) : TupleEntries<T>;
    entries<T extends any[]>(o: T) : [ string , T[number] ][];
    entries<T>(o: T): [ keyof T , T[keyof T ] ][];
}

const test1 = Object.entries({ a:1,b:2 }); //["a" | "b", number][];
const test2 = Object.entries([1,2,3]); //[string, number][];
const test3 = Object.entries([1,2,3] as const); //readonly [["0", 1], ["1", 2], ["2", 3]]
```

Comment: Fully agrre, AFAIK, there is no better solution than yours. Every time we should use type casting (as).
Btw, it returns `string[]` instead of `keyof T` because of mutable nature of JS

Comment: @captain-yossarian - well, I sometimes define a couple of overloads for the `entries` method as I stopped treating objects as mutable as soon as switched to TS (going to add them to the answer a bit later as another option), but yeah, most of the time we have to live with `string` instead of `keyof T`. As much as I flinch every time I end up using `as`, this case seems to be the only way forward (at least for the foreseeable future)

Comment: Yeah I figured. The problem was that I haven't constrained the type of the key enough so that the type system could determine the type of the mapping function. I think the type assertion would be fine in this case. Due to how we construct the map and obtain the keys, we will know that it should all work out. If there was a way to assert that the existence of a key in an object also allows us to constrain the key further, that would have been ideal, but alas it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your type. It is the builtin TypeScript lib definition for `Object.entries`. When you look at the error, it tells you that there is no index signature for `string`. That is the type of `key`. Your type has the index signature `[K in keyof T]`, so TypeScript can't find the signature for `string`. You will have to change the type to be indexed with `string`. I tried making a custom `entries` function but it didn't work because you cannot get out the value in an array type.