# Having issues with TS generics and record type mapping

Tags: typescript

### What am I trying to do?

I have an object that looks something like this:

```js
const actions = {
    foo: (state: string, action: {payload: string}) => {},
    bar: (state: string, action: {payload: number}) => {},
    baz: (state: string, action: {payload: boolean}) => {},
    qux: (state: string) => {}
}
```

And I have a generic type that looks like this:

```js
type ActionMapper<T> = T extends (state: any, action: infer Action) => any 
    ? Action extends {payload: infer P} 
        ? (payload: P) => void 
        : VoidFunction 
    : never
```

The use case for this generic type works like this:
[image]

As you can see, it extracts the type of the `action.payload` parameter from the `actions.foo()` function.

I want to be able to have a generic type that would allow me to do the same thing, but for the entire `actions` object.

### **What have I tried?**

I tried creating a generic type that looks like this:

```js
type ActionsMapper<A> = Record<keyof A, ActionMapper<A[keyof A]>>
```

but it doesn't exactly do what I was expecting:
[image]
[image]

Instead of only extracting the parameter type from `actions.foo()` it extracts it from every function and creates a type union. What I want is for the type of `mappedActions.foo()` to be `(payload: string) => void`.

Here is the playground I was using: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhsKBLcEYF4YG8CwAoGQmAMxBAC4YAKaOKAU0ugCckwBzAGnkRTEqwAHOAE8ANiDgATJlFYcAvgEoMAPmwLO+IjABGcZpRpQ6jGCzZceycAOHjJMmGACuAW131mytRq0EifQAvI1oGWXkrBBt+bHsJaUpdMjF6ODAfdHUsTW0iAEcXAA9Qk3DzOUsVLI18BXx8KBFBehgAQV5wAFk4QRbmAB4AFXVMIZh6IoYwKTRjU0p0kW5ovko2Yi92zrBq9SWYPMIAfm2Yian6GbQhUQSnDa2ABQVDgJ0T6njHSie9mAAbiAkFI3h8iJQAGrAqQAMRcYB2YIhznoAK8DTwoEgsDcvRacLIlA6MR6fS8AyaLRAxGsfAgADpSCBRl87o5-rg8HVMVTWiT6WT+gM2qyAEr0UDMKQDADW9BENPa3AF3XxFLaAG15YraW0ALqqVSY7HQGB48lSVWQYk7CBCil8pWrVCsrk6ZlGb7STm5d56Axe9k+3w5fw6YJBhwhmpho4wQolai+nnctNAA).

Comment: Please include the "test" code and types as code instead of images.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I added the playground I was using, hope that helps :)

Comment: Is it not as simple as this? https://tsplay.dev/WKrvMm

Comment: Had a question similar in nature to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66730631/how-do-i-declare-this-generic-object-type-mapping-correctly Main takeaway is that you _must_ constrain the key to be able to have it infer the correct types. I ended up taking the object map and make it into a mapping function instead.

Comment: @katniss Yes, it is. I had commented that minutes after the question was posted, but deleted it and posted an answer later.

Comment: @JeffMercado I don't see that really being related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting union types is the `Record<keyof A, ActionMapper<A[keyof A]>>`: it creates an object with all the keys of `A`, with each property having the type of `ActionMapper` applied to all the values of `A`. What you want, however, is to an object with all the keys of `A`, with each property having the type of `ActionMapper` applied to the value of *that same* key of `A`.

You can do this using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```js
type ActionsMapper<A> = {
  [K in keyof A]: ActionMapper<A[K]>
}
```

This creates the wanted object, where the key used in the value for each property is the key for that property, and just that key.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

---

The difference is that in a mapped type, you can base each value on the key for that property. With `Record`, all the values are the same.

Given:

```js
type ActionsMapper<A> = Record<keyof A, ActionMapper<A[keyof A]>>
```

Simplifying leaves the following:

```js
type ARecord<T> = Record<keyof T, T[keyof T]>
```

Here, `keyof T` is all the property keys of `T`, and `T[keyof T]` is all the property values of `T`. The two `keyof` expressions are *not linked*.

We can simplify the mapped type too:

```js
type AMapped<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
}
```

And now we can compare the `Record`-based type with the custom mapped type. You can easily see the difference:

```js
// Record<keyof T, T[keyof T]>
type RecordBased =
  { [K in keyof T]: T[keyof T] }

type Mapped =
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K]       }
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly (I had no idea there was a difference between "Record<key, value>" and "{[key]: value}") :)

Comment: Well, there isn't. The difference is that in a mapped type, you can base each value on the key for that property. With `Record`, all the values are the same.