# Typescript: function parameter have type 'never' when inferred from control flow

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, control-flow

Typescript is not resolving the correct parameter type:

`functionBuilder` takes a parameter `arg` and depending on that parameter it returns an object which contains a function property. That function takes a `string` parameter if `arg === 'a'` else it takes a `number` parameter.

```
const functionBuilder = (arg: string) => {
  if(arg === 'a'){
    return {
      f: (val: string) => {}
    }
  }
  return {
    f: (val: number) => {}
  }
}

const f1 = functionBuilder('a');
```

**The problem is that calling that function `f` on `f1` expects an argument of type `never` instead of `string`**

[image: problem]

Comment: Somewhat related (not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572797/why-does-typescript-expect-never-as-function-argument-when-retrieving-the-func

Comment: @tevemadar thank you. It seems it's not possible to correctly infer the type for now

Comment: this is a very nice question. and it takes me 20min+ to try to solve it. but end up no hope. But it look like you having [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) issue. Take a look at  [this](https://xyproblem.info/)  page

Answer (score 1):

I found that the type of functionBuilder was detected as

```
const functionBuilder: (arg: string) => {
    f: (val: string) => void;
} | {
    f: (val: number) => void;
}
```

which is the expected type. Is it not type that you want?
Like, do you want special treatment for "a"?

Anyway, consider the following (the type of f1.f is the same as Type3):

```
type Type1 = ( (val:string) => void ) ;
type Type2 = ( (val:number) => void ) ;
type Type3 = Type1 | Type2 ;
let TestVar: Type3;
TestVar(3); //Error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

It may seem odd at first, but isn't it exactly what "|" is supposed to do?
"|" means that the TestVar *can* be either Type1 or Type2. The only operations that are safe are operations that satisfy BOTH Type1 and Type2 requirements.
Number 3 does not fulfil Type1 requirement, whereas string '3' does not fulfil Type2 requirement. Indeed, no argument can fulfil both Type1 and Type2. So it's really "never".

Comment: "|" means the only operations that satisfies either Type1 or Type2 not only both. So if it was behaving like this it should work without any issue (it will work for union on non function types) so this is not the problem. The problem is it seems that typescript returns a function that accepts the intersection of the parameters of the union functions rather than their union. But he main problem is why its not regressing to the correct single type when inferring from the control flow. So the detected type of function builder is the problem since its not taking one type after looking at the flow

Comment: In union types, the only safe properties are the intersection.

See the explanation in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

"It might be confusing that a union of types appears to have the intersection of those types’ properties. 
... only the intersection of those facts applies to the union of the sets themselves. "

Comment: Think about a simpler example: <br>
let myVar: number | string<br><br>

Now if you pass this variable around, it ok to use a "myVar.toFixed()" (available to numbers) or "myVar.trim()" (available to strings)?<br>
You have to check instanceof etc before you can be sure "toFixed" or "trim" exists.
However, toString() is available to both, so you can use "myVar.toString()" always. The "usable properties of a union type" is indeed the intersection of lists of properties.  
<br><br>
In constrast, when assigning a value, myVar = 3 is accepted and myVar = "3" is also accepted.

Answer (score 0):

@qrsngky is spot on: there is no value that you can pass safely into `((val: string) => void) | ((val: number) => void)` without knowing which of the two functions it is. To solve this, you can cast the result of the `functionBuilder` call to the one you expect:

```
const f1 = functionBuilder('a') as { f(val: string): void };
f1.f('…');
```

(it might help to declare a generic helper type for this, [like here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIB4AqA+ZBvAKGWRgC5kAKANzgBtzMBKZAXlyoHtgATAbgIC+BAgg4gAzmBIBXEAjDAxAIWnBa3aK0pwoAc3KSooXczb4iyYDG17WLFsgDkcR80LFiUCGGlQQ+GApGPAEBZDhxNHRDY2x+YiFPb19-PEDg0PDIjBBpAFsAI2g4wWFRCSkYAEYtGFl5RRAVNQ0oCmdXLKiYkF0S6oA6QMdAMgJXXiA))

Comment: "|" means the only operations that satisfies either Type1 or Type2 not only both. So if it was behaving like this it should work without any issue (it will work for union on non function types) so this is not the problem. The problem is it seems that typescript returns a function that accepts the intersection of the parameters of the union functions rather than their union. But he main problem is why its not regressing to the correct single type when inferring from the control flow. So the detected type of function builder is the problem since its not taking one type after looking at the flow

Comment: @EEAH No. `((val: string) => void) | ((val: number) => void)` is either one function or the other, whereas `(val: string | number) => void)` is a function accepting either type. These are not the same.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. "Either one function or the other" is "|". With that terminology it should take either a string or a number. The problem is that function unio n is resolved to (val: string & number) => void so its returning never as a parameter. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types But in the question there is a control flow (not taken into consideration in this answer and qrsngky s answer) that should be used to override the union type and infer to one single type

Comment: @EEAH No, there's a difference between "either function" and "accepting either argument". The type is correct for the code you've written. Notice that the argument type is in a contravariant position. `functionBuilder` is allowed to return a function of the one type or a function of the other type - not a function that accepts either a string or a number! Calling `f1.f` must pass an argument that fits *all* the argument types of the possible functions.

Comment: @EEAH Maybe you meant to write `const functionBuilder = (arg: string) => (val: string | number) => { if (arg == 'a') { /* do something with string or number */ } else { /* do something with string or number */ } }`

Answer (score -1):

I tested it. It seems to compile once you add the return type as any.

```
 const functionBuilder = (arg: string) : any => {
  if(arg === 'a'){
    return {
      f: (val: string) => { console.log(val)}
    }
  }
  return {
    f: (val: number) => {}
  }
}
```

The code to executed:

```
const f1 = functionBuilder('a');
 
f1.f("a");
```

The console will emit the value 'a'.

Comment: The problem isn't  that it doesn't work as javascript. The problem is in the 'types space' of typescript. So this is not a valid answer to the question

Comment: Yes, you are right, tevemadar reference is more relevant to the question.